# Get current url

Tags: javascript

I have tried several things to get current url in JS using `window.location.href` and `document.url` but it does not seem to return me value when my URL contains some ASCII encoding reference.

For example:

```
http://locahost:5685/Display/test.jsp?value=GhMa7gwa1W2Z8777GV4HT7H936tHaUwcdoaec93y3V%2BUQJRWjTHWpPzNqyQI7qar8%2Bz0ipCFzf8DZ%2B%0D%0AbnTBmHjGE2MvlMJwvtAq6V9pRUR9P4A%3D%7Czc6xrGk9s0NsrFzGAYTD5w%3D%3D
```

It seems to break. Any ideas please?

```
alert(window.location.href);
```

When I alert using I expect the complete above URL should be captured instead it doesn't output anything.

Comment: `Please downvote or close`? Okay, but I'm doing so because your question is not clear, not because you asked. I'll retract my downvote if you fix that problem. Show some code, along with some expected output, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: I am not really sure, I just asked how to get that sample URL using window.location.href, as it does not output anything. I am not sure how to make more clear than this. Thanks.

Comment: Your JS code must throw an exception before it reaches your alert code, hence nothing is displayed. Clean it first then try again, because it should definitely work.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp May be you want this. url or URL.

Comment: @Capsule No it doesn't sample code, I think values like %2B are causing issue which are ascii encoding ref?
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="UTF-8">
   alert(document.URL);
   alert(window.location.href);
  
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
 
 </html>

Comment: @NelsonLang What do you mean it doesn't output anything? Is there an empty alert dialog opening, or no dialog at all? PS. You should use `console.log` for debugging. It's much more reliable since you can see the structure of entire objects instead of just their coercion to a string.

Comment: @Paulpro if in the above URL i just use http://locahost:5685/Display/test.jsp?value=GhMa7gwa1W2Z8777GV4H

It outputs but if I make it http://locahost:5685/Display/test.jsp?value=GhMa7gwa1W2Z8777GV4H%2B it doesn't

Comment: @NelsonLang Maybe your webserver is serving different resources for those two urls. Can you verify that if you right click and choose `View-Source` you get the same source code on both of those URLs?

Comment: It tried on my local server and, even tho I get a 404 error, I can still debug that URL in the Chrome console. I think you just have some script blocker acting weird with some of your URLs. Try in a different browser.

Comment: @Capsule Used IE, Firefox and Chrome.. Same results in all :|

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or do you use any antivirus filtering web content? I've seen antivirus modifiying or blocking JS code coming from certain pages.

Comment: A simple alert is even giving complete URL in alert. You must be doing it in wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Now I completely understood what you meant-

Try using this-

```
alert(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
```

[image]

In the above image you can see that ASCII code is properly converted to their character form.

Comment: No it isn't working. You are setting value to var and using it, how about directly fetching from URL. f.e. just make a html page with that name and try it won't work.

Comment: Dear, I am fetching from the `window.location.href` not from any variable. Let me post the full page screenshot with page url and the alert.

Comment: I just added the whole page screenshot with the alert, I tested this on the page of some project that I am working on.

Comment: Yes i did see that but sorry it isn;t working :| I will try more and see. Thanks so far

Comment: @NelsonLang: Kindly show your code, what exactly have you tried? I can also see it working. Might be you're looking for something else

Comment: Then I am sure something else might be wrong on your page, try commenting out some JS code or see if there isn't any JS error on the page using Firebug.

Comment: @NelsonLang: A simple alert is even giving complete URL in alert. You must be doing it in wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) to make sure the window.location.href is working or not. I am sure window.location.href will work, may some issues in your javascript some where.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can use this -

```
var url = window.location;
alert(url);
```

Comment: the OP already explained he tried `alert(window.location.href);`, setting this in a variable won't change a thing

Comment: You don't need to use href, only use window.location

Comment: @ManojSingh Please remove the above comment!! only `window.location` won't give the url. that gives an object, a `location` object.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary come on dear at least try it, you will get the current url

Comment: `window.location` is an object with several properties, including the `href` one. While outputting `window.location` works in most browser, this is a shortcut that shouldn't be used. Try that `for (var i in window.location) console.log(i);` and you'll see `window.location` actually is an object

Comment: Manoj, let me tell you one thing, do an `alert(window.location)`, I bet you will get the URL, then you do a `console.log(window.location)` and see what the output is. Now why this happens is upto you to research. I'm fine and safe using `window.location.href`. And as @Capsule says, `href` is one of the various properties that `location` object has.